# Superconducting loop as a particle detector?

Tags: particle-physics, superconductivity, dark-matter, particle-detectors

Imagine that one has induced a persistent current in a superconducting loop.

If a particle interacted with an electron in one of the Cooper pairs then would some decoherence and dissipation occur?

I guess if that happened then the current would be diminished somewhat leading to a detectable change in the magnetic field around the loop.

Could one use such an effect to detect particles (perhaps even dark matter particles)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryogenic_particle_detectors